# Microsoft Excel Macro - Run-time error '438'

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time doing excel macro, and I got this error:

Microsoft Excel Macro - Run-time error '438'
object doesn't support this property or method

The error is highlighted as this 
**With ActiveWorkbook.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Ad Set Name")**

Does anyone knows how to resolve this, and thanks in advance!

Best Regards
Dex

Comment: Can you please post some more complete sample code and some context for what you're trying to do?

Comment: Workbook does not have PivotTables property, probably it should be ActiveWorksheet.PivotTables

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a worksheet reference because the PivotTables collection belongs to a worksheet, not a workbook. So try:
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Ad Set Name")